# How can I make the redactor table plugin show extened options?

Tags: redactor

When I use the Redactor table plugin everything works but I can't seem to get any extended functions to work like cellpadding, cellspacing, table border color etc.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the features you're asking for are possible with the default [Redactor Table](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/table/) plugin Craft comes with, and as far as I know, it is also the only table plugin for Redactor out there.